# Update mySQL columns with random values between 2 given (with decimals)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update ratingValue column in MySql with random number between 3.8 and 5.0.

The column type in Mysql is set as Decimal (2,1) and the code I tried (with many changes, but no success) is:

```
$min = 3.8;
$max = 5.0;
$query = "UPDATE users SET ratingValue=FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+0.1)));";
$result = $baza->query($query);
```

But it never updates any value after decimal, just rounds to the full value (ie. 4.0 or 5.0).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want floating-point numbers, why you use `FLOOR` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a random number between 3.8 and 5.0 to one position.

ROUND(FLOOR(13 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 3.8

It first gets a random number between 0 and 12 then divides by 10 then adds it to 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

The RAND function in MySQL will create the desired value:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand